# How do you create a data frame from a nested xml with multiple indentations

Tags: python, xml, dataframe, web-scraping, tree-traversal

I am trying to create a data frame from an XML file, and I seem to be unable to do because the XML file has multiple nested sections within it. The indentations are denoted by `rMonthly, rSP500, rVenues and rVenue`. I tried to paste the XML file below, but unfortunately, it was completely unreadable, and the indentations did not display correctly. However, the XML file is contained in the zip files on the following website

http://public.s3.com/rule606/hood/

I am trying to create a table that would look this, that would have columns for "year", "month" and "name":

[Spreadsheet with columns for "year", "month" and "name"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuo4m.png)

I have tried to create a data frame to obtain the data from the XML, but it seems that I cannot read the elements that are nested deep in the XML. My code is as follows, but it returns `[none]` for all the variables

```
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
xtree = et.parse(xml_file)
xroot = xtree.getroot()
rows = []
df_cols = ["year", "mon", "name"]
for node in xroot: 
res = []
res.append(node.attrib.get(df_cols[0]))
for el in df_cols[1:]: 
if node is not None and node.find(el) is not None:
res.append(node.find(el).text)
else: 
res.append(None)
rows.append({df_cols[i]: res[i] 
for i, _ in enumerate(df_cols)})  
out_df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=df_cols)      
return out_df
```

Comment: @RyanM  - Thanks for your comment. I tried to edit my post. You were right that the earlier version was a complete mess. Most of the content of the earlier version of the post was a "copy and paste" of an xml file, which I have now posted a website for, so now everyone should be able to access it, so long as they can unzip the file.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot better!  Unfortunately, I don't know the answer myself, but hopefully someone will.

Comment: The indentation of several parts of the code is bad. And you should post a trimmed down version of the XML that can be used to reproduce the problem. Please read [mcve].